# problems initial Matrix in Eigen with pointers

Tags: c++

I attempted to initial Matrix with pointers in Eigen. Typically, Matrix data structure is initialized from left to right, up to down.However, I found the Matrix was initialized from up to down ,left to right.

I set a break point at code line 
`std::cout<<matrix<<std::endl`
 ,then I pressed F5 step by step, I got the flowing results:

```
1             -6.27744e+066  -6.27744e+066 
2             -6.27744e+066  -6.27744e+066
-6.27744e+066 -6.27744e+066  -6.27744e+066

1              2             -6.27744e+066 
2             -6.27744e+066  -6.27744e+066
1             -6.27744e+066  -6.27744e+066

1             2              -6.27744e+066 
2             1              -6.27744e+066
1             2              -6.27744e+066
...
```

Finally I got

```
1 2 1 2
2 1 2 1
1 2 1 2
```

instead of

```
1 2 1 2
1 2 1 2
1 2 1 2
```

I attached the original code  for you to check.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Core>

void function(Eigen::Vector2d* vec)
{
    *vec<<1,2;
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

   Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic> matrix;
   matrix.resize(3,4);
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
       for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
       {
         function((Eigen::Vector2d*)matrix.data()+2*i+j);
         std::cout<<matrix::std::endl;
       }

   return 0;
}
```

Anybody give me some instructions?

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply, I am afraid this is not where the problem lies in.Anyway, this should not be the keypoint, I update the question for you to get a better understanding of where my problem actually lies in.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out myself,`*(matrix.data()+i)`does not equally to `*((double*)matrix.data()+i)`.